# How to enable "Go to symbol" with a custom language in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have made a custom language extension and I would like to enable the "Go To Symbol" feature. I have tried to follow the guidelines [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support#_show-all-symbol-definitions-within-a-document), but I'm still kind of lost.

I think all I need to do is implement a `DocumentSymbolProvider`, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

**UPDATE**

The [example language server docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server) point to a [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node-example) that is deprecated. It is replaced with [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples), which is much more complex. I think the simplest example I can find there is the [lsp-sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/lsp-sample), but it doesn't use a `DocumentSymbolProvider`.

I've found other repos that do use symbol providers, but they are a bit overwhelming. I can't figure out what needs to go where (for example, do I need both a client and a server? Some packages only seem to use an `extension.ts` without both client and server folders).

All I really want to do in my language is detect lines that start with `@` and show them in the Go to Symbol pane. I'd love to see a simple tutorial of this.

Comment: Related: ["How can I implement my own code outline layout in vscode?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306520/how-can-i-implement-my-own-code-outline-layout-in-vscode)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Do I need both a client and a server?

Not necessarily. As the [language support docs you linked](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support#_show-all-symbol-definitions-within-a-document) show, there's usually two options: a "direct implementation" and one using the Language Server Protocol. For the former, you don't need a client / server architecture. Language Servers have the advantage of being editor-agnostic, you can theoretically use them in any editor that implements the protocol. A direct implementation is limited to usage in VSCode.

> All I really want to do in my language is detect lines that start with `@` and show them in the Go to Symbol pane.

Here's the `extension.ts` for a very simple example of a "direct implementation" for this:

```typescript
'use strict';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerDocumentSymbolProvider(
        {language: "foo"}, new FooDocumentSymbolProvider()
    ));
}

class FooDocumentSymbolProvider implements vscode.DocumentSymbolProvider {
    public provideDocumentSymbols(document: vscode.TextDocument,
            token: vscode.CancellationToken): Thenable<vscode.SymbolInformation[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var symbols = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < document.lineCount; i++) {
                var line = document.lineAt(i);
                if (line.text.startsWith("@")) {
                    symbols.push({
                        name: line.text.substr(1),
                        kind: vscode.SymbolKind.Field,
                        location: new vscode.Location(document.uri, line.range)
                    })
                }
            }

            resolve(symbols);
        });
    }
}
```

You will also need to add this to the `package.json` generated by the VSCode extension template. It registers the `foo` language and activates the extension when a file with the `.foo` extension is opened:

```json
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:foo"
],
"contributes": {
    "languages": [{
        "id": "foo",
        "extensions": [".foo"]
    }]
}
```

Here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! You totally saved me . Just for my edification, why is it okay to not provide the containerName in the [SymbolInformation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-namesymbolinformationaspan-classcodeitem-id597symbolinformationspan) object?

Comment: If you check the constructors, you'll find it's optional in one of them. In fact, it's probably better practice to call the constructor instead of constructing the object like this - I'm more used to the langauge server API. :)

Comment: @Gama11 how to append more symbols to my js or less file? I wrote the code you gave, and got my symbols replaced. All the js symbols were gone. Thanks.