# VSCode Extension Using executeDocumentSymbolProvider API

Tags: javascript, promise, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSCode extension and want to use the `executeDocumentSymbolProvider` API to get the list of functions of a file. 
I mainly have 2 problems with how to use `executeDocumentSymbolProvider`:

1. How to correctly use `executeDocumentSymbolProvider`
2. How to resolve the returned `Promise`

**How to correctly use `executeDocumentSymbolProvider`** 
Below are the links I referenced to call `executeDocumentSymbolProvider`:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands
- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command
- https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/oxnhna/get_all_symbols_of_the_current_document_in_vscode/
- [How can I implement my own code outline layout in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306520/how-can-i-implement-my-own-code-outline-layout-in-vscode)

And this is how I call the API:

```js
var active = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
let symbols = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider',active.document.uri);
```

Although this does return a `Promise`, I can't help but wonder if this is the correct way to invoke it because from the VSCode API doc it looks like I should invoke it like `let symbols = await vscode.commands.executeCommand<vscode.DocumentSymbol[]>('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider',active.document.uri)`. However I keep getting an error that says there should be an argument in the `[]`.

**How to resolve the returned `Promise`**
The following picture is the returned `Promise`.
[image]
I have tried the following methods to resolve it but I still get `Promise` instead of symbols array as the return value.

```js
async function(){
    var active = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    let symbols = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider',active.document.uri);
}
```

```js
var active = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider',active.document.uri).then((symbols) => {
    if(symbols !== undefined){
        console.log(symbols);
    }
});
```

```js
async function getFunctionList(textEditor){
    var active = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider',active.document.uri));
        }, 1000);
    });
    
}
```

Please let me know if you have used `executeDocumentSymbolProvider` before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to install the C/C++ Extension Pack by Microsoft on VSCode for getting symbols from a c file. Otherwise, VSCode won't be able to find the symbols.