# VSCode Get current file hierarchy (outline)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On VSCode API, is there a way to get the file structure hierarchy (the outline)?

For example, let's say I have a markdown file opened, I want to get the structure, token, parsed result in any form of the document, so I can pass the data to my extension program (and render on the Treeview for example).

I googled some and found a issue on Github such as [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66990), or SO posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846146/make-vs-code-parse-and-display-the-structure-of-a-new-language-to-the-outline-re), according to my research I could use something like `vscode.DocumentSymbol.children`, but this code doesn't show an output. (I could expect this since I just tried to run to see if it works by chance)

So how is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Choose from menu:

View -> Open View

In the list that is shown scroll down and select 'Outline'

Good luck!