# How to activate "Peek definition" function to custom language

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am wondering if there is a way to activate VScode peek definition function for a custom language.

I am writing cadence skill using it, but I can highlight the syntax but not be able to use this to locate the definition quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Peek Definition" uses the same funcionality under the hood as the regular "Go to Definition". You need to implement a [`DefinitionProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DefinitionProvider) using [`vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerDefinitionProvider). For a code example, check out this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054953/2631715) of mine.

Alternatively, if you're using the language server protocol instead of coding against the VSCode API directly, the [Goto Definition Request](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_definition) needs to be implemented.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help on developing, but I wonder if you know how to highlight the code in peek definition window?

Comment: The range you specify in the result should take care of that.. Or what exactly do you mean by highlighting?

Comment: by passing the range as the parameter, it works. thanks, there should be a light yellow colour to highlight the definition part, that's what I mean, appreciate for the help