# How to add elements to Outline panel in custom extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VS Code extension for ST language support. Right now it provides only syntax highlights and some snippets. I wanted to create a tree structure of the document showing programs, functions and their parameters in the Outline panel. But I cannot find an example of how to do that.

Can you refer me to the right direction but not to LSP as it is too complicated for now I want to make it programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outline view is populated by a [`DocumentSymbolProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbolProvider) (see also: [`registerDocumentSymbolProvider()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerDocumentSymbolProvider)). In the language server protocol, this corresponds to the [`textDocument/documentSymbol`](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_documentSymbol) request.

All in all, it currently provides the data for all of these:

- Outline view
- Breadcrumbs
- Go to Symbol in File

You can find an example implementation of one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054953/2631715), though you'll want it to return `DocumentSymbol` rather than `SymbolInformation` instances. Only the former [supports the hierarchy needed](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_document-symbols) for the outline view via it's `children` property.

Comment: Perfect! ше took a while to get everything up, but finally, it works. Thank you.